# In ngx-bootstrap 7.0.0, dropdown is not closed after clicking on another one

Tags: ngx-bootstrap

Versions：
ngx-bootstrap: 7.0.0
Angular: 12.1.3
Bootstrap: 4.6.0

Clicking on a dropdown button after another dropdown is opened, the first dropdown is not closed.

But in ngx-bootstrap@6.2.0, it didn't happen.

How can I solved this issue? Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same problem today. Turns out this is an unsolved issue that's been looked at by the Angular bootstrap Community. My guess is that it will be resolved soon.

https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/6248

However as a work around:
An element with the `dropdown-menu` class is shown by adding the `show` class.
So you could give every menu a ref:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" #menu1>...</ul>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" #menu2>...</ul>
```

And upon a click event on any dropdown navigation item, trigger a function that removes the `show` class on all of these elements.